# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_mysql'

Tags: python-3.x

Hope for a nice answer, my environment is python3.6.7 for windows ,the edion if pycharm is 2018.3.5。

Comment: Explain brief about the problem and your tries to solve the problem